# Как сделать так, чтобы я мог вводить числа в список n-ное количество раз через пробел?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input())

numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
a = 0
b = 1
#нахождение суммы
for i in numbers:
    if i > 0:
        a += i
max = max(numbers)
min = min(numbers)
#нахождение произведения
if numbers.index(min) > numbers.index(max):
    sum = numbers[(numbers.index(max)+1):(numbers.index(min))]
if numbers.index(min) < numbers.index(max):
    sum = numbers[(numbers.index(min)+1):(numbers.index(max))]
for i in sum:
    b = b * i
print(a, b)
```

Проблема в том, что в моем коде никак не задействуется переменная n, которая должна задавать количество вводов чисел в список numbers. Причем вводить обязательно нужно через пробел! Если использовать

```
 for i in range(n):
    numbers = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

то данные вводятся только через enter. Как оформить ввод как в условии задачи, чтобы числа вводились через пробел?

Comment: А вам так хочется, чтобы она использовалась? Данная переменная задается для удобства ввода в языках, в которых считывание идет посимвольно, как например в c++,  который является первым по популярности в олимп проге, а не построчно, как в питоне,

Comment: @EzikBro, ладно, в таком случае как решить задачу, чтобы ввод условию соответствовал?

Comment: А ваш первый код не соответствует?

Comment: Ну как бы задача засчитывается, но хотелось бы, чтобы переменная n была не просто для галочки, а имела хоть какую-то пользу. А так она служит лишь избежания ошибок встроенных тестов сайта.

Comment: Коротко - в питоне нет встроенных функций, парсящих ввод типо scanf (и cin соответственно) в c и c++. Но вы всегда можете написать велосипед, ради того, чтобы просто использовать переменную n, а не игнорировать ее. Для этого вам нужно полностью считать ввод с помощью sys.stdin.read(), а потом парсить его как вам понравится. Также сейчас нашел "простую" реализацию scanf в питоне: https://code.activestate.com/recipes/502213-simple-scanf-implementation/, поэтому желаю удачи. Правда даже эта реализация считывает построчно, а потом возвращает все значения в строке, так что она вам особо не поможет.

Comment: Ну а что делать, если язык изменился, и старые задачи не обновили. Если мешает наличие переменной, можно её не создавать, бросить на первой строчке `input()` и всё, вреда не будет) А вот `max = max(numbers)` тут косяк, встроенному имени `max` присваивается новое значение. Теперь это число, второй раз уже нельзя будет использовать функцию max. Называйте `max_` или как-то по другому. То же самое и для sum.

Comment: Также, если вы сильно желаете использовать n, то можете написать numbers = numbers[:n], но будьте готовы к тому, что это абсолютно бесполезно на нормальных тестах, а на ненормальных ошибка скорее будет в n, чем в списке чисел

Comment: Окей, спасибо))